# Table losing it's top border when viewed in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Take a look at the following page:
https://www.wholesaleledlights.co.uk/dimmable-b22-6w-omni-led-clear-globe.html

The large product specification table displays perfectly well in firefox and ie, but is missing it's top border when I view it in chrome.

I'd be very interested to know why..

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table {
/* border-collapse: collapse; */
border-spacing: 0;
}
```

change the style of table in style.css line no 788

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this should happen if you're using the -webkit- prefix in your

`<table class="data-table"....>`

But a quick fix would be to add a `border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0` attribute to your H2 titled **Specification Table**

Tried in Firefox, worked great.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Chrome hasn't been webkit for years.

Comment: my bad, force of habit... Thanks for the heads-up anyway